# What does 'through/before' mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, range-inclusion

[Here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-33/product_id-47/year-2017/Linux-Linux-Kernel.html) has some examples:

> ... inet_connection_sock.c in the Linux kernel through 4.10.15 allows attackers to ...
>
> ... Linux kernel 3.12 through 3.15 ...
>
> ... io_ti.c in the Linux kernel before 4.10.4 allows local users to ...

What does "through/before" mean here?

1. Does 'through 4.10.15' mean all version before 4.10.15, including '4.9.0 - 4.9.27(without 4.9.28+)', '4.8.0 - 4.8.17' and so on?
2. Does '3.12 through 3.15' mean all of '3.12.0 - 3.15.10'?
3. Does 'before 4.10.4' mean '4.10.0 - 4.10.4' without 4.9.* or another main version?

Comment: "X Through Y" means starting with version X, all versions until (and including) Y.  "Through Y" (with no X) means all versions until (and including) Y.  "Before Y" means all versions until (but not including) Y.  Of course these are all tempered with an implicit "from the version where this code first appeared".

Answer (score 4):

There is a little difference between them:

- ["through" means "until and including"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/through_1?q=through)
- "before" means "until" without including

For example,

- through 4.10.15: versions before 4.10.15 and version 4.10.15
- before 4.10.15: versions before 4.10.15

The meaning of "before" is usually in terms of numerical order. However, it is advisable to read the [Linux kernel versioning](http://www.linfo.org/kernel_version_numbering.html)

Comment: In _British English_, **inclusive** is used: "Answer questions 8 to 12 inclusive."
In _North American English_, **through** is used: "Answer questions 8 through 12."